# Fantasy novel in which the protagonist's house is a portal to a fantasy world where he reinvents guns, telegraph, railways, etc

Tags: story-identification

Need help in finding out the name of a novel I read; it came out after 2010. There are two novels released.

The hero's house is the site of a portal to a magical fantasy land and the villain comes from there to Earth to get modern tech to fight in their fantasy world. But the hero is taken back to that world during a confrontation at his house.

There he battles against a magical beast and defeats it with a gun as the bullets are copper jacketed which is anti-magic so could penetrate the magic shield of the beast but its extremely rare and expensive in that world.

There he reinvents gunpowder, railways, telegraph, etc to fight against the villains and he also learns magic as well. The villain uses chemical weapons etc in response.One of the sides uses hot air balloons as well.

In the second novel he comes back to earth and brings sniper rifles and other things to fight the wizards.

Comment: You've provided a lot of details, which is good, but take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to see if there are any more details you can [edit] in.

Comment: I've read an awful lot of SF/Fantasy stories that fall into the basic category of "the hero, or a small group of characters, ends up in a primitive and/or magical environment (time travel, parallel world, alien planet, whatever), and 'invents' all sorts of 19th and 20th Century technology to give him (and his new friends) a **huge** advantage." I call them "Connecticut Yankee" stories, in honor of a novel by Mark Twain, who may well have *invented* this entire subgenre when he wrote *A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court.* But I don't think I've read this particular specimen.

Comment: I too am a voracious reader of sf and fantasy and agree that this a common premise but this is a bit unique in the sense that the villian also has access to earth and tries to get modern technology for himself so it becomes a race between both of them to see who can  industrialise  faster and smarter.Not sure if it's the right place but can you point to a couple of more novels with this kind of premise as I am interested bin this genre.

Comment: @pranav paruchuri -- Here are some of my favorites (and I'll probably remember more, later). 1) *Lest Darkness Fall* by L. Sprague de Camp. 2) *The Cross-Time Engineer* (1st of a series by Leo Frankowski). 3) *Lord Kalvan of Otherwhen* by H. Beam Piper. (Some sequels were later written by other people, but I don't like them as much.) 4) *Sword of the Bright Lady* (1st of a series that isn't finished yet) by M.C. Planck. 5. *Island on the Seas of Time* (first of a trilogy by S.M Stirling).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I haven't read most of the ones  you mentioned as I seem to have read novels which are more recent.Which is very good as finding unread novels is a very difficult problem for me.Will read all the novels you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

This reminded me a lot of [Guardians of the Flame by Joel Rosenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Flame), but even the newest novels are older than 2010.

At the very least, it sounds like Guardians of the Flame might of inspired or shared similar inspirations to the one you are looking for.

[image]

Here is the plot summery from Wikipedia:

> Guardians of the Flame is a long-running series by author Joel
>   Rosenberg and is arguably his best-known work. The series is about a
>   group of college students who participate in a fantasy role-playing
>   game, and are magically transported to the world of the game by their
>   gamemaster.
>
> The first book, The Sleeping Dragon focuses on the former students
>   struggling to survive in the world of the game. The series progresses
>   with the students choosing to live in the 'game world' and forming
>   their own community, which is in part based on opposition to the
>   ubiquitous slave trade.
>
> In the later books, the focus shifts from efforts to destroy the slave
>   trade and on to various characters dealing with the changes in the
>   fantasy world wrought by the former students (now mostly
>   40-somethings). The final three books shift focus to a new set of
>   protagonists, relegating the 'Other Siders' to supporting cast and
>   cameo appearances.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But that is not it.Some of the differences are the protoganist is a single person while in guardians of flame its 4-5 people of both sexes who are changed to different dnd type characters while in this book there are no changes to the person on transport through the portal and another difference is the portal is stable i.e travel both ways is possible relatively easily at a specified place in both worlds for both people and equipment.And this has more of http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GivingRadioToTheRomans going on here than in guardians of flame.